# PayPal IPN doesn't return custom field

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm implementing a payment system in my website using PayPal. Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem with the IPN. I have the hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="ZjozNDoiABmpmZmJiZmlrkAFmaXWSEnF6Yk5dtZThpIALrYysVnOKyI7">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://someip.com/process_payment.php">
```

The URL is called, but the custom field is not returned. I tried the IPN simulator from sandbox.paypal.com and everything works like a charm, but when I pay, the http://someip.com/process_payment.php is being called without the custom field. Where can the problem be?

The code I use to fetch the IPN request is from PayPal's examples:

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
```

When I use the IPN Simulator tool $myPost['custom'] contains the needed data, but when I use the normal approach, there is no data in the custom field.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will get the custom data during IPN call.
According to you its working.
So what is the issue ? I could not get what is normal approach.
Can you please explain ?

Comment: The normal approach is when someone PAYS via PayPal, then the IPN doesn't send the custom field. However, it sends the custom field when I'm using the IPN Simulator tool.